# How to disable Filestream on SQL Server 2008 R2 to enable mirroring?

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring, sqlfilestream

I'm enabling database mirroring on SQL Server 2008 R2, I've already configured my servers but when trying to start mirroring I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Database Properties
------------------------------

An error occurred while starting mirroring.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Alter failed for Database 'PlaneamientoComercialDB'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4000.0+((KJ_PCU_Main).120628-0827+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Alter+Database&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

A database cannot be enabled for both FILESTREAM storage and Database Mirroring. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5574)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5574&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I don't even have files on my database so I'd like to turn off filestream, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I found the following when scripting the database:

ALTER DATABASE [PlaneamientoComercialDB] ADD FILEGROUP [fsGroup] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
GO

Is there a way to alter the filegroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have any columns that uses FILESTREAM, for some reason I had a filegroup containing filestream.
I could solve the issue by removing the filegroup

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDBName
REMOVE FILEGROUP MyFileGroupName
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when trying to test mirroring between 2 qa servers.  Right click database --> Properties --> Filegroups

Remove filestream and click ok.  Make sure to do on both servers or it will still fail.

Answer (score 1):

FILESTREAM is configured at the server instance level. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to disable. Under SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services. Find the service, right-click, properties:

[image]

Comment: I did it on the principal, mirror and witness server but still get the same error.
Ive also tried restarting the whole server
Thanks

Comment: Try disabling using SQL Server Configuration Manager

Answer (score 0):

[Database Mirroring and FILESTREAM data not allowed](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/40887)

Just to verify, I tested out Database Mirroring with the full version of AdventureWorks2008 and, although it let me setup the Mirroring endpoints, it did not allow Mirroring to start giving an error 5574: `“A database cannot be enabled for both FILESTREAM storage and Database Mirroring”.`